# How can I create prompt restricted to report data in OBIEE?

Tags: obiee

In OBIEE, how can I create a dashboard prompt using data which is populated in  the report.

For Example: Possible data values are ID1, ID2, ID3. But in my report I have only ID1, ID2. How can I create a prompt where it should display only ID1 and ID2 as options, not all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a dashboard column prompt, you can change the "Choice List Values" drop down from "All Column Values" to SQL Results. Then just take the logical SQL your report runs (get this SQL from the Advanced tab), and plug it in here, eliminating anything extra in the SQL.

If these ID1, ID2 values are not dynamic and do not change, you can hand pick choices using the "Specific Column Values" option. This hard codes the choices though, and may not be right for you.

Comment: query But It is not working in this case. Can we provide join condition in that query because in the log there is no join condition for high level query. Only join condition is present for Physical query. Please provide some solution , how to get only those values in the prompt which are present in the report view.

Comment: Edited. Use the logical SQL that the report runs (with only the ID column). Grab that from the advanced tab in the report. This logical SQL must have all the correct joins, or else your report would not work.